# Execution of multiple shells in parallel in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I tried to execute a shell(outershell.sh) which calls 3 different shell parallely:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh &
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/nmshell.sh &
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InP/nmshell.sh &
```

The contents of the nmshell.sh are same in these three locations:

```
#!/bin/sh
../MAIN/lm47.run lmctl 
../MAIN/lm47.run lmes 
echo "lmes done"
```

The error comes as:

```
~/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort$ ./nmshell_multiprocessing.sh 
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/nmshell.sh: 2: /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/nmshell.sh: ../MAIN/lm47.run: not found
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh: 2: /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh: ../MAIN/lm47.run: not found
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InP/nmshell.sh: 2: /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InP/nmshell.sh: ../MAIN/lm47.run: not found/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/nmshell.sh: 3: /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/nmshell.sh: ../MAIN/lm47.run: not found
/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh: 3: /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh: ../MAIN/lm47.run: not found
lmes done
lmes done
```

I also tried to replace `../MAIN/lm47.run lmctl` by the full path `/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/MAIN/lm47.run lmctl`

Now, the error comes as:

```
~/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort$  Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
 *** Program aborted ***
lmes done
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
lmes done
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
 Error  : OPEN_SETUP: Error opening SETUP file
STOP  *** Program aborted ***
lmes done
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You should quote the calls since there is an asterisk included: `"/home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/GaSb/nmshell.sh" &`

Comment: This seems to be an error within the `~/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort` program... It cannot open the setup file (?)

Comment: Thanks, @Am_I_Helpful. I include the " " , but the problem continues. When I run the commands going to the addresses, they run fine, so, maybe there is no problem in the program. I mean that going to /home/sujoy/LMTO-NMTO/2*vLB-NMTO-47.ZB.46.6/06.gfort/InAs/ and executing nmshell.sh works fine

Comment: Thank u @napuzba for editing my question and making it far more understandable